# Alternating table row colors in freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker

What's a good, simple way to have alternate row coloring with [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)?

Is this really the best way?

```
<#assign row=0>
<#list items as item>
    <#if (row % 2) == 0>
        <#assign bgcolor="green">
    <#else>
        <#assign bgcolor="red">
    </#if>
    <tr style='background-color: ${bgcolor}'><td>${item}</td></tr>
    <#assign row = row + 1>
</#list>
```

I tried doing this:

```
<#assign row=0>
<#list items as item>
    <tr style='background-color: ${(row % 2) == 0 ? "green" : "blue"}'><td>${item}</td></tr>
    <#assign row = row + 1>
</#list>
```

But apparently you can't user the ternary operator in there.

**Note**: I guess I should have mentioned it earlier, but I can't use css classes or javascript, since this HTML is going into an email message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a series of tables you might want to make a little function.

```
<#function zebra index>
  <#if (index % 2) == 0>
    <#return "white" />
  <#else>
    <#return "#efefef" />
  </#if>
</#function>

<#assign arr=["a","b","c","d"] />
<table>
<#list arr as n>
  <tr><td bgcolor=${zebra(n_index)}>${n}</td></tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

and the [_index builtin](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_list.html) when using list saves you from having to make and increment an index variable yourself.

Comment: And please use "clean" CSS: add the relevant class when needed (class="odd" or class="even") & then style in the CSS accordingly (ie. .even{ background-color: grey; } .odd{ background-color: white;}

Comment: Furthermore, in 2.3.23, if the class names are `even` and `odd`, you can write `<td class="${n?item_parity}">`.

Answer (score 27):

```
class='${["odd", "even"][item_index%2]}'
```

Comment: Note: Replace "item" above with the variable for the list.  For example, <#list array as line> ... [line_index%2] ... </#list>

Answer (score 8):

With freemarker, you can use the `string` built-in:

```
<#list items as item>
   <tr style='background-color: ${((item_index % 2)==0)?string("green", "blue")}'><td>${item}</td></tr>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm... OK, this is the best I've come up with:

```
<#assign row=0>
<#list items as item>
    <tr style='background-color: <#if (row % 2) == 0>green<#else>red</#if>'><td>${item}</td></tr>
    <#assign row = row + 1>
</#list>
```

From the deafening silence I deduce there's no nicer way of doing this.

Comment: You do realize that you could use CSS or JavaScript to do the same thing: There's no need to use FreeMarker?

Answer (score 1):

A solution then boils down to this:

```
<style>
.rowon {
 background-color:#dedede;
}

.rowoff{

}
</style>
```

In your template:

```
<#list items as item>
    <tr  class="<#if item_index % 2 ==0>rowon<#else>rowoff</#if>"><td>${item}</td></tr>
</#list>
```

However, as stated in a previous reply, you can do this with CSS, without this freemarker solution (see http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd):

```
<style>
.striped tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #eee}
.striped tr:nth-child(even) {background: #fefefe}
</style>
```

And then just use a normal table without classes on the rows:

```
<table class="striped">
 <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
 <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
 <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
 <tr><td>hello</td></tr>
</table>
```

OR with a freemarker generated table:

```
<table class="striped">
<#list items as item>
    <tr><td>${item}</td></tr>
</#list>
</table>
```

So it is all in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In FreeMarker 2.3.23:

```
<#list items as item>
    <tr style='background-color: ${item?item_cycle('green', 'red')}'><td>${item}</td></tr>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using FreeMarker, there are limited ways of answering this question, but if you're wanting to use CSS alone (Which still allows separation of concerns), then here's one way:

**Put the following in your stylesheet:**

```
tr.linea {
    background-color: #CC9999; color: black;
}
tr.lineb {
    background-color: #9999CC; color: black;
}
```

**Then use the following `tr` class to define alternate lines**:

```
<table>
<tr class="linea"><td>One Fish</td></tr>
<tr class="lineb"><td>Two Fish</td></tr>
<tr class="linea"><td>Red Fish</td></tr>
<tr class="lineb"><td>Blue Fish</td></tr>
</table>
```

There are [many resources](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=Use+CSS+to+alternate+colors+in+a+table&fp=Rhq7p-mUk-o) to choose from as well.

**Edit**: If your HTML is going into an email, then you can't be sure that the client's email client will allow whatever HTML you're trying to put into it.  Your best bet at that point is to use FreeMarker similiar to how you have it, except that you need to remove the `style` tag, and use colors for each row using `bgcolor="color"` in your `<tr>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate ternary operator in FreeMarker using the following construction:
${condition?string(result_for_true, result_for_false)}.

```
<#assign arr=["a","b","c","d"] />
<table>
<#list arr as n>
    <tr><td bgcolor=${((index % 2) == 0)?string("white", "#efefef")}>${n}</td></tr>
</#list>
</table>
```